# Zooming an image inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, pinchzoom, fresco

I have a `ScrollView` and it contains an image(I am using [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) to display the image) and below the image are some additional information about the image, which can be scrolled down.

What I want is to be able to pinch and double tap zoom the image. When this image zooms, it should take as much height as it need on scaling and if the scaled image's width goes beyond the dimensions of the screen, it should be horizontally scrollable. I also want the info below the image to go further down as the image scales to take up more height.

Currently, I am using [PhotoDraweeView](https://github.com/ongakuer/PhotoDraweeView), a library on top of [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) for zooming. In my current implementation, when I zoom the image, it scales within the view bounds of original image and does not change it's height to push down the info below it. I think this is easily doable in iOS as you can specify which element to zoom in a `ScrollView`. How can it be implemented in Android?